# Zend Framework : Get bootstrap resource from anywhere in application

Tags: zend-framework

i wonder how do i get any bootstrap resource from anywhere in the application. eg. Zend_Validate, Zend_Auth_Adapter etc?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
$resource = $bootstrap->getResource('whatEver')
```

Comment: it doesnt work in crons, is there any REALLY universal method to fetch bootstrap that will work both in web and cli?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this: http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/235-A-Simple-Resource-Injector-for-ZF-Action-Controllers.html

That will make it easy passing it to the controller. From the controller you can then pass individual resources to the other things you need.

Comment: that will give u access to ur resources from the controller right? what if i want to get them in my `Zend_Validate` or `Auth` classes?